# Getting an unhandled promise rejection error while running electron-windows-store

Tags: node.js, electron, appx

I am trying to convert my electron app to appX using electron-windows-store and have been getting this error. My version of windows 10 sdk is Windows 10 SDK, version 1903.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> electron-windows-store --input-directory C:\Projects\Javascript\simplephotoviewer\dist\simplephotoviewer-win32-x64 --output-directory c:\projects\javascript\simplephotoviewer\dist\AppX --package-version 1.1.0.0 --package-name simplephotoviewer
You need at least Node 4.x to run this script
? Did you download and install the Desktop App Converter? It is not required to run this tool. No
? You need to install a development certificate in order to run your app. Would you like us to create one? No
Welcome to the Electron-Windows-Store tool!
```

This tool will assist you with turning your Electron app into
a swanky Windows Store app.

We need to know some settings. We will ask you only once and store
your answers in your profile folder in a .electron-windows-store
file.

```
? Please enter your publisher identity: CN=IggyMakesThings
? Please enter the location of your Windows Kit's bin folder:

Setup complete, moving on to package your app!

Configuration:
Desktop Converter Location: undefined
Expanded Base Image: undefined
Publisher: CN=IggyMakesThings
Dev Certificate: undefined
Windows Kit Location:

(node:15548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
at inquirer.prompt.then.then (C:\Users\igweo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-windows-store\lib\params.js:86:29)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:15548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15548) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Would appreciate any help